# Spring JPA repository throws exception when trying to run native query with TO_TIMESTAMP function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I run the below update query in sqldeveloper, it works fine and updates the specified column of the table, however, when I use the same query in spring boot it throws an exception.
Java version: jdk1.8.0_171
Spring version: 2.3.3.RELEASE
Sql Developer version: 18.4.0.376

Query used in sqldeveloper is:

```
Update ETL_EXTRACT_JOB_DETAILS set LAST_EXTRACT_DT = TO_TIMESTAMP('11-NOV-20 21:26:00.00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS.FF') where TENANT_ID = 'c1' and JOB_ID = '2011051116'
```

query used in the repository class that extends JpaRepository is:

```
@Modifying
    @Query(value= "UPDATE ETL_EXTRACT_JOB_DETAILS SET LAST_EXTRACT_DT = TO_TIMESTAMP(?1,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') WHERE TENANT_ID = ?2 and JOB_ID = ?3", nativeQuery = true)
    int setLastExtractDateFor(String lastExtractDate, String TenantId, String jobId);
```

values used for the above arguments in setLastExtractDateFor: lastExtractDat = "11-NOV-20 21:26:00.00",
jobId = "2011051116",
TenantId = "c1"

Exception thrown by java is:

```
[org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:403), org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257), org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528), org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61), org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242), org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212), com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3937.setLastExtractDateFor(Unknown Source), oracle.apps.bi.etl.services.service.impl.EtlSchemaService.updateLastExtractDateFor(EtlSchemaService.java:366),
```

Comment: We have a partial stack trace, but not the error message or the root cause from the stack. Try looking in the logs instead of the returned json.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have 'DD-MON-YYYY... in your @Query?